# Differential equation with polynomial powers

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

```
Sin[f t] == y[t] + y[t]^3 + y'[t] + (y'[t])^3
```

Where `f` is a constant, the frequency of the oscillation. I have tried using `DSolve` and `NDSolve`, but I cannot get a solution due to the cube in the equation. With `NDSolve` I gave initial conditions of

```
y[-Pi/f] == y[Pi/f]
```

and domain

```
{t, Pi/f, -Pi/f}
```

Does anybody know how this equation can possibly be solved?

Comment: What is `f`? an expression or a parameter?

Comment: f is a constant. It's the frequency of the oscillation in my problem. Sorry. I edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use ParametricNDSolveValue

```
ode =  Sin[f Pi t] == \[Gamma][t] + \[Gamma][t]^3 +Derivative[1][\[Gamma]][t] + Derivative[1][\[Gamma]][t]^3
gamma = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, \[Gamma][0] == \[Gamma]0}, \[Gamma], {t, -10, 10}, {f, \[Gamma]0}]
```

to solve your problem for initial condition `\[Gamma][0] == \[Gamma]0`

What you call "intial condition" is only a restriction to force symmetrie `\[Gamma][t]==\[Gamma][-t]`

Perhaps you can calculate, for given `f`,  the parameter `\[Gamma]0` to restrict the symmetrie?

To force symmetrie at `t=10` try `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[gamma[f, \[Gamma]0][10] == gamma[f, \[Gamma]0][-10], {f, 1,3}, {\[Gamma]0, -.1, .1}, MaxRecursion -> 3,FrameLabel -> {f, \[Gamma]0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I wanted to restrict the symmetry of the solution, since I am also expecting symmetry in Gamma (or y after editing). 

Can you expound on the calculating Gamma0? Apologies, I'm new to Mathematica and still familiarizing a lot of the syntax.

Comment: What do you know about the parameters `f,\[Gamma]0`?

Comment: f is a constant, it's the frequency I use in my experiments. The reason why I restrict the symmetry is because that's the only part of the curve that have values I know for sure, so the value at `\[Gamma][0]` and `\[Gamma]0` itself are unknown to me. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Step I edited my answer!

Comment: I ran your suggestion on solving for the `\[Gamma][0]==\[Gamma]0` but would you care to explain how the ContourPlot can force the symmetry at t=10?

I think I have to keep the symmetry at the endpoints `\[Gamma][-t]==\[Gamma][t]`

Comment: `ContourPlot` solves the equation(1st argument)  and plots possible solutions `f,\[Gamma]0` . I took `t=10` as endpoint. Unfortunately I have no idea how to force symmetrie for arbitrary `t`.